# Check which RPMs depend on this package

Tags: shell, rpm, dependencies

I want to get a list of packages which depend on requested package. For example, I want to get all packages, which depend on `telnet`. I came up with this script:

```
for i in `rpm -qa | sort`;
   do rpm -qR $i | grep telnet > /dev/null;
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo $i;
   fi;
done
```

Is there a better way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command you need is:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires <packagename>
```

Therefore:

```
rpm -q --whatrequires telnet
```

*From the man page*

> ```
>   --whatrequires CAPABILITY
>          Query all packages that require CAPABILITY for proper functioning.
> ```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that tells you packages that depend on the given *capability*, not on the given *package* as the original question asked.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, `rpm -q --whatrequires` is sometimes insufficient:

```
$ rpm -q --whatrequires perl-libwww-perl
no package requires perl-libwww-perl

$ rpm -e perl-libwww-perl
error: Failed dependencies:
       perl(LWP) is needed by (installed) perl-XML-Parser-2.36-7.el6.x86_64
```

That is because `--whatrequires` takes as its argument a *capability name*, and not a *package name*.  If (as is often the case) an RPM package provides only a single eponymous capability, giving that package's name as `--whatrequires` argument works just fine; but if not (as in the above `perl-libwww-perl` example), we need another solution.

---

#### Solution #1: `rpm --test -e`

Give the `--test` ("dry-run") option with `-e`; if command succeeds (without actually changing your system!), there are no dependencies:

```
$ rpm --test -e emacs-common && echo 'No dependencies!'
No dependencies!
```

; if it fails, you get the error output we already saw above:

```
$ rpm --test -e perl-libwww-perl && echo 'No dependencies!'
error: Failed dependencies:
       perl(LWP) is needed by (installed) perl-XML-Parser-2.36-7.el6.x86_64
```

---

#### Solution #2: `repoquery --installed --whatrequires`

The `repoquery(1)` command, which comes as part of `yum-utils` RPM, knows enough to resolve package names to capability names and vice versa:

```
$ repoquery --installed --whatrequires perl-libwww-perl
perl-libwww-perl-0:5.833-5.el6.noarch
perl-XML-Parser-0:2.36-7.el6.x86_64
perl-libwww-perl-0:5.833-5.el6.noarch
```

Downsides:

- `yum-utils` might not already be on your system
- `yum` (which `yum-utils` requires) might not already be on your system
- Does not deduplicate output (easily fixed by appending `| sort -u`)
- Does not filter out input package name (also easily worked around)

---

---

So, although Solution #1 is kludgey, overall it appears more reliable and simpler to use.

Comment: I suggest a third solution:rpm -q --whatrequires $(rpm -q --provides perl-libwww-perl | perl -anE 'say $F[0]') | grep -v 'no package' | sort -u

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #3: `rpmdep --depending`

Instead of showing package dependencies (rpm -qR), display packages wich are depending upon the given argument: rpmdep then act as an improved `rpm -q --whatrequires` command. [taken from rpmdep man page]

I would also like to note that solution #2 requires a lot of packages to be installed. On openSUSE Leap 15.4, zypper resolved dependencies to 23 packages (3.7 MB) in total which needed to be installed, only to enable the repoquery command.

rpmdep is one of the utilities in the rpmorphan package. It is similar to `rpm -q --provides` / `--requires`, the main difference being that it works on packages, not on capabilities. Which is exactly what the OP asked for.

Examples:

```
$ rpmdep --depending firewalld
no depending : firewalld is an orphan

$ rpmdep --depending iptables
iptables is needed by firewalld
```