# RHEL/CentOS - How can I find all rpm packages which depends on a particular package?

Tags: centos, rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

Linux distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)

Context: 
I need to uninstall all old versions of Java in my server.
I have the list of java paths, example:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

I can find the pacakage owning this file by:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64/jre/bin/java
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64
```

Now, how to find all packages depending on `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64` , so that I can see whether it is safe to remove the package ?

Below command says no other packages depends on this openjdk package (Ref: [Question-166343](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166343/check-which-rpms-depend-on-this-package)):

```
rpm -q --whatrequires  java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64
no package requires java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64
```

**But**, `mysql-connector-java` depends on this package.
Reason: rpm `--whatrequires` option's argument is CAPABILITY provided by a package , not package name and searching using CAPABILITY is not straightforward.

Below command was also not returning any results:

```
repoquery --requires --resolve --recursive java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64
```

**So, is there any simple way to identify all rpm packages which depends on a particular package?**

By package , I mean `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64` (not `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless`)

Comment: Did you install the java package via `yum`?

Comment: Yes. Installed via yum.

Comment: Add the script that you have so far to your question.

Comment: I see in other questions the "yum deplist" option; alternatively, you could run a test-remove: `yum --assumeno ...` or `rpm --test ...`

Comment: @JeffSchaller `yum deplist` would show the packages on which it depends but not what depends on the package itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Normally `rpm -e` doesn't uninstall a package if there are other packages that are dependent on this package [ of course `--nodeps` can be used to by pass this ]. As @JeffSchaller mentioned `rpm -e` can also be used in conjunction with `--test` to see if there are any `error: Failed dependencies:`

```
--test Don’t really uninstall anything, just go through the motions.  Useful in conjunction with the -vv option for debugging.
```

`rpm -e -vv  <package_name>`      -- check for `error: Failed dependencies:`

or

`rpm -e -vv --test <package_name>`      -- check for `error: Failed dependencies:`

For more refer `man rpm`

Comment: An example I used: rpm -e mysql --test -vv 2>&1 | grep 'Failed dependencies'